# MySQL installation on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, mysql, installation

I'm trying to install MySQL 5.1 on a Windows Server 2008, but I'm just not getting even after trying a million different things.

The installation actually goes smoothly, but I can not start the service - it gives me an "Error 0" (but sometimes just an error)

Already tried uninstalling, deleting all folders, regs,etc. and reinstalling but still nothing.

Heres the my.ini:

```
[client]
port=3306
[mysql]
default-character-set=latin1
[mysqld]
port=3306
basedir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/"
datadir="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/Data/"
default-character-set=latin1
default-storage-engine=INNODB
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
max_connections=100
query_cache_size=0
table_cache=256
tmp_table_size=9M
thread_cache_size=8
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=17M
key_buffer_size=10M
read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
sort_buffer_size=256K
#skip-innodb
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=2M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=1M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=17M
innodb_log_file_size=10M
innodb_thread_concurrency=8
```

Does anyone have any idea about how to go ahead with this?

EDIT:

Looked up event viewer and got this:

***Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.***

Comment: does it start if you use skip-innodb?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the problem exactly but I can give you some hints to try out.

1. Add a firewall exception.
2. Disable UAC.

Those are the things that can make some strange problems. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to search in the event viewer an error about mysql, maybe you can find more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can start mysqld on safe mode  througt cmd shell  to have a verbose execution!

Answer (score 0):

make sure the C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/Data/ folder exists, and there really isn't supposed to be a space in "ProgramData".